# 200k data (1.3 GB) in mongo collection and query return result is very slow NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am using React, Node and MongoDB.

I have sent the request from ReactJS through API. I have a collection in Mongo with more than 200k data and the collection size is approx. 1.3 GB.

I am using the keyword search in 2 columns with like condition but query will take more than 1 minute to return the result. Below are the Node function that return the result:

```
// Schema for my_master_data
const FboSchema = new mongoose.Schema({},{ collection : 'my_master_data' })
const FboModel = new mongoose.model('my_master_data', FboSchema);

exports.getSolData = async (req, res) => {
    const keyword = req.body.keyword;
    let searchp = {}
    let dataavl = ""
    if (keyword && keyword != '') {
        searchp = {
            $or: [
                { subject: new RegExp(keyword, "i") },
                { desc: new RegExp(keyword, "i") }
            ]
        }
        dataavl = 'avl'
    } else {
        searchp = {}
        dataavl = ""
    }
    
    if(dataavl && dataavl!==''){
        await FboModel.find(searchp, {subject: 1, date: 1, solnbr: 1, naics: 1, classcod: 1, tbltype: 1, agency: 1, office: 1}, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                res.send({message: err})
            }else{
                if(data){
                    res.send({message: "Data fetched Successfully", fbodata: data})
                }else{
                    res.send({message: "No Record Found"})
                }
            }
        })
    }else{
        res.send({message: "Please select atleast one search criteria"})
    }
}
```

I have applied the Indexing on searched column (subject and desc).

```
desc.$**_1       WILDCARD     837.2MB    2 since Fri Sep 17 2021
subject.$**_1    WILDCARD     5.6MB      2 since Fri Sep 17 2021
```

please let me know if any other details required.

Comment: Note from [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/): *Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.*

Comment: So what's the solution for this?

Comment: If you make your regex case sensitive you will have some improvements since the search will be done on the index rather than the collection. However keep in mind there is a lower bound on how fast this can actually be since you need to do a regex match in each string in an index which this particular regex seems to be linear in the size of the string

Comment: Below updated code is also take time to return the result:

```
searchp = {
            $or: [
                { "subject": /.*technology.*/ },
                { "desc": /.*technology.*/ }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Since the string values in the index are sorted lexicographically, the regex that is not anchored to the beginning of the string cannot efficiently use the index.  Also, accoding to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/#multi-field-query-predicates), only 1 wildcard index can be used to service a single query.  You might try a text index that includes both fields, and the `$search` operator.